# How to write a batch file to append each item (of a list of directories read from an external file) to PATH?

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

How can I translate the batch file from

```
rem working batchA.bat
PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.07\bin
PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader
PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application
PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\cwRsync\bin
PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\PDF Labs\PDFtk Server\bin

setx PATH "%PATH%" /m
```

to

```
rem NOT working batchB.bat
for /f "delims=" %%x in (List.txt) do (PATH=%PATH%;%%x)
setx PATH "%PATH%" /m
```

where `List.txt` contains the following.

```
C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.07\bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application
C:\Program Files (x86)\cwRsync\bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\PDF Labs\PDFtk Server\bin
```

?

Comment: Is doing it with PowerShell an option for you?

Comment: @Windos: Unfortunately No. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you are having is that the variables are expanded on the FOR line only once, so when you loop though it %PATH% is no longer a variable.

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in (List.txt) do (PATH=%PATH%;%%x)
```

Becomes this BEFORE the loop is even run:

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in (List.txt) do (PATH=C:\Windows;Blah;Blah;%%x)
```

You can solve this using delayed expansion as Karan said, but I've never had much luck with that. I always recommend a function when using for loops.

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%x in (List.txt) do call:loadpath "%%x"
setx PATH "%PATH%" /m

Exit /b 0

REM -------------------------

:loadpath
SET PATH=%PATH%;%~1
Exit /b 0
```

Notes: use "tokens=*" to get the whole line from the file. Double quote "%%x" when calling the function to place every word in %1. Use %~1 inside the function to strip the double quotes from the value.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: sorry about that, I missed that your directories had spaces in them.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried every way I can think of to implement this how you want to get it going, but keep running into road blocks like you have already seen.

There are a couple of options which aren't quite as nice to use, but will still get the job done:

**1. Setting up the variables on one machine, exporting them and reusing them on another.**

*Adapted from [how to set environment variable from file contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767017/how-to-set-environment-variable-from-file-contents)*

On a machine that has the paths setup already, run:

```
echo %PATH%> dat
```

This will create a file called dat which contains the full path from the reference machine.

You can then reapply them on a different machine by passing it into the command:

```
set /P PATH=< dat
```

It should be possible to edit `dat` such that it only contains the paths you want to append to a machine and modify the command like so:

```
set /P PATH=%path%;< dat
```

Note that I have not tested this modification.

Going forward you could add any changes to `dat`.

**2. Using a third party app, pathed.exe**

*Using info from [Edit the PATH environment variable in Windows without pain](http://op111.net/82/)*

Using [Pathed](http://www.p-nand-q.com/gtools/pathed.html), part of the [gtools](http://www.p-nand-q.com/gtools.html), you can append the path.

Assuming your list is List.txt and you're in the same directory as the list, the command would look like this:

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in (List.txt) do (pathed /append %%x /machine)
```

You'd also need pathed in your path or in the same directory you're working in.

**2. Using PowerShell**

You could also look into PowerShell, but you've already indicated this isn't an option (plus option 1 or 2 should be able to see you right.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%x in (List.txt) do (PATH=!PATH!;%%x)
setx PATH "!PATH!" /m
```